# Drupal 6, giving user ability to create microsites

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I built a website that allows a user to create event pages with schedules etc... But now I want to give more options which can be used to build more of a minisite or microsite. So along with the usual options of adding a gallery, description etc.. I want them to be able to add a sub menu, and a custom background. I think the background is easy. However, for the submenu I don't really want to give access to the menu options. I would like to still use nice menu though.

I would love some suggestions as to the best way of adding these features while making it really intuitive for the users. Something like a Microsite node that allows everything to be set on one page perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Open Atrium?  http://openatrium.com/
This is a Drupal distribution that lets you create microsites.